# Jquery confirm dialogue not working in Content Place holder

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to use a JQUERY Confirm dialogue that asks the user to either press ok or cancel. It is working fine until i put in a page that is inside a masterpage. The confirm alert gets shown for a millisecond and disappears.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  $("#ehi").click(function() {
    $.confirm({
      title: 'Are you sure you want to approve this application? Note: This action cannot be reverted. An automatic email will be sent to the student to notify him/her of the decision.',
      content: '',
      buttons: {
        confirm: function() {
          $.confirm({
            title: 'Confirmed confirmation!',
            content: 'Simple confirmation!',
            buttons: {
              confirm: function() {

              },
              cancel: function() {

              },

            }
          });
        },
        cancel: function() {

        },
        somethingElse: {
          text: 'Something else',
          btnClass: 'btn-blue',
          keys: ['enter', 'shift'],
          action: function() {
            $.alert('Something else?');
          }
        }
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.2.3/jquery-confirm.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.2.3/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>


<button id="ehi" class="btn btn-info">confirm</button>
```

Please note that this works fine in a regular webform or page. So all the imported links are fine. But whenever i put inside a page included in a masterpage it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `jquery-confirm.min.js` file after including `jquery.min.js`. All these scripts should load before executing your code.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  $("#ehi").click(function() {
    $.confirm({
      title: 'Are you sure you want to approve this application? Note: This action cannot be reverted. An automatic email will be sent to the student to notify him/her of the decision.',
      content: '',
      buttons: {
        confirm: function() {
          $.confirm({
            title: 'Confirmed confirmation!',
            content: 'Simple confirmation!',
            buttons: {
              confirm: function() {

              },
              cancel: function() {

              },

            }
          });
        },
        cancel: function() {

        },
        somethingElse: {
          text: 'Something else',
          btnClass: 'btn-blue',
          keys: ['enter', 'shift'],
          action: function() {
            $.alert('Something else?');
          }
        }
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.2.3/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
<button id="ehi" class="btn btn-info">confirm</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <button id="ehi" type="button" class="btn btn-info">confirm</button>
```

**OR**

```
$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_ehi").click();
```

try this way.

Comment: No i'm afraid that's not the issue. Because the confirm dialogue is showing but for milliseconds and disappearing. I guess the masterpage is causing some sort of refresh page